# Confluence page - get list of editors

Tags: confluence

In Confluence, I'm trying to find (using the Java API) the list of users who have edited a page, and the number of edits, if possible.
Similarly, I want to find the number of watchers a page has.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to do get the history of page editors is with `PageManager`'s API. Eventually I used a code like this:

```
Set<ConfluenceUser> users = new HashSet<ConfluenceUser>();
List<VersionHistorySummary> historySummary =   pageManager.getVersionHistorySummaries(page);
for (VersionHistorySummary version : historySummary) {
    users.add(version.getLastModifier());
}
return users.size();
```